# Using abraham's twitteroauth: The "followers/ids" next_cursor is always 0

Tags: php, twitter-oauth

twitteroauth has been fantastic up until now, but I'm having trouble gathering all of the followers of certain users.

For example:

```
$method = 'followers/ids';
$params = array("screen_name"=>"governoromalley","cursor"=>"-1");
print_r($conn->get($method));
```

Returns / Prints the object **claiming that there is only a 0 for next_cursor**:

```
stdClass Object ( [previous_cursor_str] => 0 [next_cursor] => 0 [ids] => 
Array ( [0] => 353642204 [1] => 98012791 [2] => 72607824 [3] =>...
```

But, when curling via the http://dev.twitter.com OAuth tool, I get something showing that the **next_cursor is there**, but I can't seem to get it via the PHP SDK.

```
{"previous_cursor_str":"0","next_cursor":1380213447767347311,"ids":
[23639237,324619439,282668815,...
```

How can I solve this conundrum? I'm willing to do any silly hacks as necessary.

*Thanks for any help!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up figuring it out. 
Seems like twitteroauth sdk wants user_ids instead:

```
//Where GovernorOMalley's user_id = 15824288
$method = 'followers/ids/15824288'; 
print_r($conn->get($method));
```

Gives the proper cursor elements.